# Is there a quick way to render only the Z depth / pass in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, render-passes

Hi I'm almost finished rendering an 820 frame animation and just discovered that the Z pass is missing! Argh! ... Anyone know of a quick way to render out only a Z depth pass in Cycles without rendering the actual image?

Comment: I think I just discovered the answer... the z pass doesn't depend on samples so perhaps the fastest way is to set render samples to 1 and use a file output node for the Z pass?

Comment: You may also optionally use Blender Render instead, which might be faster depending on scene.

Comment: I'd probably create a simple *Diffuse Material*, enable *Material Override* and set the samples to 1.